# Distinct record from two joined tables, one "distinct" field, controlling date

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, distinct

Access 2007

```
TableA  
IDx      Filename  

TableB  
IDy     Date     Name
```

There are more fields in Table B, but this should work.
IDy is not unique, may have duplicates.
IDx is unique, no duplicates.

What I started with:

```
 SELECT TableA.IDx, TableA.Filename, TableB.Date, TableB.Name  
 FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.IDx = TableB.IDy
```

Where I am trying to get to:
(As stated in my other question, which I believe was too generic to answer the intent. I could not convert the elected answer to work with two tables and could not add a comment in the allotted space to re-ask the question with more detail.)

List of distinct records based on TableA.ID with most current record from TableB based on TableB.Date if IDx=IDy produces duplicates.

I hope this is understandable.

Comment: Trying to understand. If you post some data for both tables (a few lines each) and then a desired visual output, you'd get response faster...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should probably solve your problem:

```
SELECT a.IDx, a.Filename, b1.Date, b1.Name
FROM ((TableA AS a)
  LEFT JOIN TableB AS b1 ON a.IDx = b1.IDy)
  LEFT JOIN TableB AS b2 ON b1.IDy = b2.IDy AND b1.Date < b2.Date
WHERE b2.IDy IS NULL
```

Limiting the output of `TableB` to only the rows with the latest `Date`s for every `IDy` is done through a crafty device, which involves joining `TableB` back to itself and searching for the rows where for any given `Date` there are no dates greater (later) than that.

Turns out, it's basically the same as John Gibb's solution, only it involves `LEFT JOIN` (the second one) + `WHERE key IS NULL` instead of `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Unfortunately, Access will no accept the second LEFT JOIN statement. (Syntax error, missing operator)

Comment: @Mhonzell: Fixed (the required parantheses were missing).

Comment: With the parenthesis, this now works as John Gibb's solution behaves in that it does not filter anything. (Includes all records.) BUT... If the word DISTINCT is placed after the first SELECT, then this works as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work in MS Access, but worth giving it a try:

```
SELECT TableA.IDx, TableA.Filename, TableB.Date, TableB.Name  
FROM TableA, TableB
WHERE TableA.Idx in (SELECT DISTINCT TableB.IDy FROM TableB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, try this tie breaker written as a left join.

```
select * 
from TableA a
 left join TableB b
   on b.idy = a.idx
  and b.date < a.date
where b.idy is null
```

Comment: `outer apply` is not Access/Jet/ACE-compatible SQL.

Comment: NOT EXISTS (as well as NOT IN) is not well-optimized in Jet/ACE because it doesn't reliably utilize the indexes on both sides. In most cases, an outer JOIN is going to be preferable because it will always use the indexes.

Comment: I do not believe the OUTER APPLY works in Access.  In the second version, this format is accepted, but results in a list of records which includes all records. There is no filtering occurring.

Comment: whoops, now I see that andriy beat me to it ;)  Oh well!